# Concerting duration (hh:mm:ss) to integer return invalid literal for int() with base error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a python script to send some data to BigQuery. I have a duration column in my dataframe with the following format `hh:mm:ss`

As far as I can see type is `non-null object` and I need to convert it to integer to send it to BigQuery.

I wrote the following line:

`as_run_df['duration'] = as_run_df['duration'].astype(int)`

which returns me the following error:

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00:58:29'`

What should I do?

Comment: How do you want to convert it to an int?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then get seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
as_run_df = pd.DataFrame({'duration':['00:58:29','00:58:30']})

#column is filled by strings
as_run_df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(as_run_df['duration']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (as_run_df)
   duration
0      3509
1      3510

#columns is filled ty times objects
as_run_df['duration'] = (pd.to_timedelta(as_run_df['duration'].astype())
                           .dt.total_seconds().astype(int))
```